# The browser does not redirect to idp - ADFS

Tags: adfs2.0

This is my scenario:

1) Web Application - adfs01.domainA.local/app/default.aspx - DomainA - (sets as Relying Party on ADFS01)

2) ADFS01 - adfs01.domainA.local - DomainA - (sets as Relying Party on ADFS02)

3) ADFS02 - adfs02.domainB.local - DomainB - (sets as Claim Provider on ADFS01)

I developed the step 1 and 2 following the instructions described on TechNet article (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx)
Aftewards I decided to add a new ADFS server (ADFS02) as Identity Provider and trusted it with ADFS01 then I tried to connect to web application with a DomainB's user (eg. domainB\user) logged in a DomainB's workstation.

In this way the web application redirects the browser to ADFS01 and it asks me username and password (in my case with the form).

Why does ADFS01 ask me the credential, instead of redirect the browser to ADFS02 to retrieve the token and authenticate me on Web Application publish on DomainA? Depend of application or ADFS01 configuration?

Please help me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clear all your cookies. Then you will get a Home Realm Discovery screen which will ask you which ADFS you want to authenticate against.